# How do i save changes back to database from wpf toolkit datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, toolkit

i write this code in my project:

```
        DatabaseDataContext dataContext = new DatabaseDataContext();

        IQueryable<Available_Time_Teacher> att = from r in dataContext.Available_Time_Teachers
                                                 where r.Teacher_ID == id
                                                 select r;            
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = att;
```

when i change in tables in datagrid how the change can submit on database.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to save your changes to the database, then you need to call

```
dataContex.SubmitChanges();
```

Every item that was changed at the datagrid will be saved to the database.